# Cordova - starts with a url

Tags: cordova, url

How can I start by loading an website that is mobile friendly?

Pretty much I want to say load http://www.google.com as soon as I open this app.

I heard about Cordova InAppBrowser plugin, but I was wondering if there is a way without using any plug in. Just a simple coded needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. This code is executed on a same processor.

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system');
```

And this code operates in a manner 'open' in another processor.

```
navigator.app.loadUrl('https://www.google.com/', { openExternal:true });
```